# Simple query not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, echo

I am trying to get a single value from the database. Somehow it does not echo out. I know about the security deprecation and will use PDO later on this is just as test. I filled in the correct table. When I use the sql I have in phpmyadmin it correctly gives me the value i want.

```
  <?php
    include 'connectdb.php';

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);


    echo $row["id"];

    mysql_close();

   ?>
```

Comment: it's a better practice to add `mysql_error()` to check if there's any error. So try this, `$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die("Error :: " . mysql_error());` to check if any error is reported

Comment: `echo $row[0];` as [`mysql_fetch_row — Get a result row as an enumerated array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: I trust that your table isn't really called 'table'!?!?!?

Comment: @Sean make your comment an answer and itll get accepted and upvoted... for more rep :)

Comment: I don't really understand the point of fetch_row. Why not always use fetch_array? The overhead must be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per the docs ->`mysql_fetch_row — Get a result row as an enumerated array` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php
so you want

```
echo $row[0];
```

--
note: also from the docs -> **Warning** [`mysql_` functions/] extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and related [FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use this:

```
echo $row[0];
```

instead of

```
echo $row["id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do this in mysqli (as you point out, you should not be using mysql_ functions)

You can put $con elsewhere and use include each time you use a query. (Replace the values in the connection string with what they actually are, in your case.)

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost',$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_dbname); if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con)); } mysqli_select_db($con,"xyz");

$result = mysqli_query("select id from table order by id desc limit 1");

$result_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $result_row['id'];

?>
```

Comment: Also thanks for your advice, isnt PDO the better option? I want to do PDO later.

Comment: It depends, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons , http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: Thanks once again :) will look into this!